# What are good places to test the Sunhallowed Elven Arrow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am thinking of places with tons of enemies on the surface. I just shoot the sun and watch them die. So basically a surface-only dungeon with TONS of enemies.

Also want to test Odahviing and Durnehviir.

Comment: -4 really? I looked up answer and answer it my self. I found the place, I tested the bow. Meh.

Comment: I got a -4 myself today as well. Kind of annoying because no-one commented as to why. It was closed as off topic, at least that tells me something.

Comment: @user4951 are you treating this site as a way to get your questions answered, or a way to gain internet points? maybe it's a good idea to adjust your attitude towards our site. the points aren't important, the quality questions and answers are important.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? I want answers. I searched the net I couldn't find it. I think many people would ask the same question. It is a reasonable question with reasonable answers. I got enough points.

Comment: @user4951 You may want to revisit our site guides on asking good questions, and learn from there. Users downvote low effort questions, and questions that are confusing or don't seem to have a singular goal. Your recent Skyrim questions have shown just that. If you take issue with this, I encourage you to post on Arqade Meta where maybe a better discussion can be had.

Answer (score 2):

> a surface only dungeons with TONS of enemies

No such place exists in Skyrim or Solsteim. The undead are underground, that's where dead people rest: in tombs or catacombs. Even the word 'dungeon' [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dungeon#Etymology) "underground", "subterranean" etc.

That's not to say you don't get them on the surface, you do, but it's a rare event [outside of the last location in the Undeath quest mod springs to mind, but even then there aren't many].

You may have to look further into mods. But it's a hard question to answer because it's quite out of context and lore. Skyrim does not do "tons" of enemies, it's a 'less is more' game. It's not Left4Dead.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are such places because I've been fighting 5-8 enemies at once on surface.

One such place is

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Bard%27s_Leap_Summit

Bard Leap Summit.

It has tons of enemies on the surface. Also I think one wiki says it's the only "surface only" dungeon.

I tested the bow. The result is meh. It kills a lot but took so many arrows to kill them all. The sun is hard to see. Often behind clouds. On 11 AM to 1 PM it sort of works because the sun is on top (looks like skyrim is in equator?)

However, after that it's hard to see the sun.

I finally got bored, use my 2 hands death brand armors + swords, and mass murder them much more quickly.

Comment: Well, you *do* know this effect is only good for undead? For example Arcwind Point is a place this could be useful. BTW Clear Skies shout can help with clouds.